# Access a webpage:PORT even when the port is blocked

Tags: networking

On my working computer, I try to access my Synology NAS Web panel (DSM) which is listening on the port 1452.

I noticed the port is blocked by the IT department. What can I do to access my Web panel without changing the port on my Synology Diskstation to for example port 80?

Can I somehow install a service on my Synology Diskstation that if I access a specific URL on port 80 it redirects me to the DSM web panel without loading it on my client on port 1452?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), which from what I think it internally does is, it sets up ssh tunnel between your firewalled PC and the internet. It also gives you a DNS name for the same.

I think you should be good with the free plan, since it might be easier than SSH, VPN, or port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do this would be to set up a server that redirects from 80 to 1452 with something like [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/) but ultimately you still need to communicate with 1452, so if NGINX is somewhere that can't reach that port you won't have it.

If you have a way to install the web panel yourself you can try to set it up inside  [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/) which you can tell to bind its 1452 container port to the host's 80 port.

Shorter solution however is asking IT to whitelist the port.

Comment: Or use a SSH tunnel.... or a VPN.